# Transpose irregular data from .txt import to a table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have imported a bunch of data from tables in Word -> .txt -> Excel, but in the conversion to .txt the format of the table is lost and I am now trying to recover it in Excel.

I would just make a simple Copy/Paste Macro based on the Cell Range, but the cell ranges are not the same across each imported .txt file so this won't work as the same data could be in A8 in one sheet then A10 in another.
You could *almost* move every other row into column B, but the "Date Due" field throws it out of sync.

I want to transpose the copied date into a more functional table format - [see picture for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swMEn.png) - which I can then analyze. I need to do this for hundreds of sheets but I'm hoping that if I can get it working for one then I can adapt it to work across many.

Each sheet may have multiple products, each new product is preceded by an integer (e.g. 1. Product1; 2. Product2 etc...)

*deleted old code that I'd tried to do*

EDIT2:
[screenshot of typical notepad file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dVEY.png)

There is a load of text above this, but the first product always starts with QUOTATION MACHINE SCHEDULE, then 1. xxx

EDIT3:

Tried to add in the column **I** to have **Quote Ref:** and find this in the text file, but it didn't work. Code change from CDP1802 current solution below

```
'results sheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
ws.Range("A1:I1") = Array("Item", "Date Due", "Type", "Serial Number", "Standard", "Mode", "Range", "Location", "Quote Ref:")
r = 1 ' output row
```

---

```
 Select Case s
    ' match word to set column
    Case "type": c = 3
    Case "serial number": c = 4
    Case "standard": c = 5
    Case "mode": c = 6
    Case "range": c = 7
    Case "location": c = 8
    Case "Quote Ref:": c = 9
    Case Else: c = 0
 End Select
```

[New Screenshot for Quote Ref:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxgtc.png)

Comment: You can go through header entries for each record in turn. If you find the next header entry without having previously found a value to enter for the header, you skip the current column. But apart from that ... Why do you take the diversion via a text file? I don't know VBA for Word, but I'm sure it's easier to access the Word tables directly.

Comment: I could only see an option in Excel to import data from text, I couldn't see anything that would let me import Word documents

Comment: Like you can handle with cells and other objects in Excel, you can also handle with objects in Word. What you need is the *table obeject* I think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table You have to look how to get access to a Word document from Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text file into an array and then scan for key words using Select Case. Reading the data into an array allows you to select the value from the  row below the key word.

update - Quote Ref added

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessTextFiles1()

   Const FOLDER = "C:\temp\SO\Data\" ' folder where the text files are

   Dim ws As Worksheet, sFilename As String, sQuoteRef As String
   Dim n As Integer, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
   Dim fso As Object, ts As Object, ar() As String, s As String

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   ' results sheet
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
   ws.Range("A1:I1") = Array("Item", "Date Due", "Type", "Serial Number", _
                              "Standard", "Mode", "Range", "Location", "Quote Ref")
   r = 1 ' output row

   ' scan each file in folder
   sFilename = Dir(FOLDER & "*.txt")
   Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
        n = n + 1
        sQuoteRef = ""
        
        ' open file and read into array
        Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FOLDER & sFilename)
        s = ts.readAll
        s = Replace(s, vbLf, "")
        ar = Split(s, vbCr)
        ts.Close
        'MsgBox sFilename & "=" & UBound(ar)

        ' parse the strings in the array
        i = 0
        Do While i <= UBound(ar)
            s = LCase(Trim(ar(i)))
            'Debug.Print s
            If Len(s) > 0 Then ' skip blanks

                If Left(s, 10) = "quote ref:" Then
                    sQuoteRef = ar(i + 1)
                End If

                If Left(s, 2) Like "#." Or Left(s, 3) Like "##." Then
                    ' new product
                    r = r + 1
                    ws.Cells(r, 1) = ar(i)
                    ws.Cells(r, 9) = sQuoteRef
                Else
                    Select Case s
                        ' match word to set column
                        Case "type": c = 3
                        Case "serial number": c = 4
                        Case "standard": c = 5
                        Case "mode": c = 6
                        Case "range": c = 7
                        Case "location": c = 8
                        Case Else: c = 0
                    End Select

                    ' take value below
                    If c = 4 Then
                        ws.Cells(r, 4) = ar(i + 1)
                        ws.Cells(r, 2) = ar(i + 2) ' due date
                        i = i + 2
                    ElseIf c > 1 Then
                        ws.Cells(r, c) = ar(i + 1)
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        sFilename = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox n & " Files processed", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, I tried it this morning but I just get "0 files processed". It seems to be falling down at this - sFilename = Dir(FOLDER & "Word*.txt") - point. The filenames don't really have a consistent pattern, other than they all start with "Q", but even if I just have ".txt" it returns 0. I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong...

Comment: @user167 If they start with Q then use `"Q*.txt"` the `*` is any number of characters. If the folder only has the text files you want to process then use `"*.txt"`

Comment: thanks for explaining! I still get the same issue though, skips right to the end even with `"*.txt"` .  If I change it to `Do While Len(sFilename) >= 0` then it moves onto the next section, but then I get an run-time error 70, permission denied. (edit: it fails at this section `Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(FOLDER & sFilename)`)

Comment: yes I'm on Windows. I have set `Const FOLDER = "C:\temp\textfiles"`. All files in that folder are .txt extension, even if I manually add .txt to the name it still errors.

Comment: @User167 You need a "\" on the end because it is a folder `"C:\temp\textfiles\"`. That is so `Dir(FOLDER & "*.txt")` becomes `Dir("C:\temp\textfiles\*.txt")`

Comment: d'oh! Yes that's got it working properly, thanks for hand holding me through this! On running it a couple of time, some files it doesn't pull data through and others it gets the right info, but puts it all into column A..

Comment: have added a screenshot at the end under EDIT2

Comment: @User167 OK that look's like I expected. I have updated the code to raise a message box after each file so you can see if the lines are being read in correctly.

Comment: Wow that worked great, I'm very impressed, thanks so much! One last point if you can still help, I noticed I missed the "Quote Ref:" from the table. I can add it to row I of the array easy enough, but having the script copy the value down wasn't as easy as putting `Case "QuoteRef:": c = 9`, is this an easy update for you to make?

Comment: @User167 I can't see QuoteRef in the screenshots, does it have a colon at the end `QuoteRef:`?

Comment: Sorry it's above what I snapped. Its written like: `Quote Ref:` - space between the words, colon at the end. Then on the line below it is the reference, e.g. Q130512R

Comment: @user167 you have `Case "QuoteRef:": c = 9` without space

Comment: I spotted & corrected that, but still doesn't populate the column. I've copied the code I have used under EDIT3 above.

Comment: @user167 `s = LCase(Trim(ar(i))` converts the line to lower case so you need to use `Case "quote ref:": c = 9`

Comment: OK yes that has made it pull the information across, really appreciate your help on this! For some reason just that column is starting in row 1 (I1 rather than I2), but I can easily just add something at the end to shift everything down one row and re-add the Header

Comment: @user167 That's is because the Quote Ref comes above the 1. Product Name line which triggers a new line. Does every product have a quote ref ?

Comment: Ah OK got it. No, each text file will have one Quote Ref, but there may be multiple products per file. I've added a screenshot trying to show how it outputs.

Comment: Amazing! Yes that's perfect thanks so much